# Shell (ssh) into Azure AKS (Kubernetes) cluster worker node

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a Kubernetes cluster in Azure using AKS and I'd like to 'login' to one of the nodes. The nodes do not have a public IP.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: You should be able to login to aks with `az aks get-credentials --resource-group myAKSResourceGroup --name myAKSCluster`

Comment: @Hackerman that logs-in "kubectl" so to speak. I want to shell-in to one of the worker nodes... I want to get into the linux shell of the actual VM

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Comment: I deleted my answer, and also thanks for the downvote. The choosen answer has really poor quality, but, it's ok.

Comment: sorry @Hackerman, my down vote was meant to be feedback that you misunderstood my question; if there is a way to take it back, I will do that; maybe restore the answer and I will take my down vote away

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The procedure is longly decribed in an article of the Azure documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh. It consists of running a pod that you use as a relay to ssh into the nodes, and it works perfectly fine:

You probably have specified the ssh username and public key during the cluster creation. If not, you have to configure your node to accept them as the ssh credentials:

```
$ az vm user update \
  --resource-group MC_myResourceGroup_myAKSCluster_region \
  --name node-name \
  --username theusername \
  --ssh-key-value ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

To find your nodes names:

```
az vm list --resource-group MC_myResourceGroup_myAKSCluster_region -o table
```

When done, run a pod on your cluster with an ssh client inside, this is the pod you will use to ssh to your nodes:

```
kubectl run -it --rm my-ssh-pod --image=debian
# install ssh components, as their is none in the Debian image
apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-client -y
```

On your workstation, get the name of the pod you just created:

```
$ kubectl get pods
```

Add your private key into the pod:

```
$ kubectl cp ~/.ssh/id_rsa pod-name:/id_rsa
```

Then, in the pod, connect via ssh to one of your node:

```
ssh -i /id_rsa theusername@10.240.0.4
```

(to find the nodes IPs, on your workstation):

```
az vm list-ip-addresses --resource-group MC_myAKSCluster_myAKSCluster_region -o table
```

Comment: The link you used is updated, but this is what is was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This [Gist](https://gist.github.com/tsaarni/624d5406e442f08fe11083169c059a68) and this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ssh) have pretty good explanations of how to do it. Sshing into the nodes and not shelling into the pods/containers.

Comment: Although sometime SSH'ing into a node is necessary, you should be able to do anything you need using a DaemonSet, and this approach is also more scalable (as you scale your cluster, the DaemonSet is applied to every new node). You mount hostPaths from the node (or the whole fs) like in this [comment](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/590#issuecomment-412075626).

Comment: thanks @Rick, I did not yet try this (i found another way of investigating my issue) but read the article and this seems exactly what I wanted to do so thanks for the answer!

Comment: @alev this was just for investigating some networking at the node level. not really a production process

Answer (score 0):

you can use this instead of SSH. This will create a tiny priv pod and use nsenter to access the noed.
https://github.com/mohatb/kubectl-wls

Comment: The linked page might answer the question but it might become unavailable. So please add the relevant details from there here to make it persistent and findable via search.